# What is Gitlab's Graphql Endpoint?

Tags: python, graphql, gitlab

I am trying to connect to Gitlab's graphql. I have been banging my head for two hours but haven't found the Graphql endpoint? What is the proper graphql address? Below is my python code

```
import requests
url = 'https://gitlab.gnome.org/api/graphql'
query = '''
    {
        group(fullPath: 'World/design') {
            id
        }
    }
'''
headers = {
    'Private-Token': '<my-access-token>',
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, json=query, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: em ? why are You sending GET request with body ? as I am aware the whole `graphql` is operating fully on POST, when You need to use GET the query should be passed as url-queryparam.  here is doc : https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/

Comment: Have you resolved your issue? I am having the same problem. Using GraphQL Playground, using the endpoint documented in GitLab's documentation: https://<gitlab-instance>/api/grapql, I get a 500 error. Unable to connect to the server.

Answer (score -1):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. According to their [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/)
"https://gitlab.gnome.com/api/v4/" is the base URL you are looking to hit. Appending "projects" on the end should show a list of projects in your instance of Gitlab. See more under their [Basic Usage](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#basic-usage) section.

They also provide an [IDE](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/using-the-explorer/) to explore the API with which may be helpful as you are getting started. I assume this is for a self hosted version of Gitlab. To improve your question you should add a link to the documentation that is confusing and how you implemented it. That way, those of use familiar with the environment can help troubleshoot what the real issue is.

Comment: I think OP was asking about GitLab, not GitHub.

Comment: Doh! It appears that is the case.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I am looking for Gitlab graphql. I don't know what the endpoint is, so I can't add the response.

Comment: See the updated response. It should be for a hosted version of GitLab now.